# How to use mutex to lock only once and write multiple times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have two sets of dates in the format of number of days since 1900-01-01.

I'm trying to share them between threads so they could add dates or read from the set.

However, my code is locking the set based on dates, which means each time I read/write a date, I need to lock it then release it, and this is not very efficient in my context.

I'm wondering if there's a way to only lock the set once and write all the dates into it?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <map>

std::unordered_set<int> calendar_uk{ 44197,44288,44291,44319,44347,44557,44558 };
std::unordered_set<int> calendar_us{ 44197,44214,44242,44347,44382,44445,44480,44511,44525 };
std::map<std::string, std::unordered_set<int>> cal_map;
std::shared_mutex CalendarMapMutex;

void init()
{
    cal_map.insert(std::make_pair("US", calendar_us)); 
    cal_map.insert(std::make_pair("UK", calendar_uk));
}

void addDate(const std::string& country, int aDate) {
    std::lock_guard<std::shared_mutex> writerLock(CalendarMapMutex);
    std::unordered_set<int> calendar = cal_map[country];
    cal_map[country].insert(aDateInt);
}

void readDate(const std::string& country, int aDate) {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> readerLock(CalendarMapMutex);
    std::unordered_set<int> calendar = cal_map[country];
    std::unordered_set<int>::const_iterator got = calendar.find(aDateInt);
    if (got == calendar.end())
        std::cout << aDateInt << " is NOT found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << *got << " is found" << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    std::thread reader1([] { readDate("US", 47828); });
    std::thread reader2([] { readDate("UK", 45660); });
    std::thread writer1([] { addDate("UK", 41228); });
    std::thread reader3([] { readdDate("US", 42984); });
    std::thread writer2([] { addDate("US", 47980); });

    reader1.join();
    reader2.join();
    writer1.join();
    reader3.join();
    writer2.join();
}
```

Comment: *I'm wondering if there's a way to only lock the set once and write all the dates into it?* Sure, why not. What did you try? What problems did you run into? SO is not a code writing service. Also, the function names and calls in your `main` does not match. Typo?

Comment: What's the actual problem with creating a function like, say, `addDates` that would take some container of dates and add them to your data structure after locking the mutex once?

Comment: @alagner The issue is that I have hundreds of thousands of dates, and the threads write multiple dates into the sets. So if I lock/release the sets for every date, the program gets very slow.

Comment: You're making a pointless copy of `calendar` in the `addDate()` function. In the `readDate()` function you're also making a copy of `calendar` that could be a reference instead.